# High quality, detailed images of planets on web

Tags: planet, photography, nasa

I have been looking for images of the planets and have found pretty decent ones of Earth and [Venus](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/688/computer-simulated-global-view-of-venus/?category=planets_venus) from NASA.

[image]

That detail is opposed to this one of Uranus:

[image]

And these of [Mars](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/opo0124a/), (and [this](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/opo0745a/) and [this](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/opo0534a/))

[image]

I am disappointed in the quality of the public domain images from NASA I have found for these planets:

- Mars
- Jupiter
- Saturn
- Uranus
- Neptune
- Pluto
- Earth's Moon

I am happy with the ones found for:

- Mercury
- Venus
- Earth

They seem to be high quality in terms of detail and pixel size (in the MBs).

Wondering if one could explain how I go about finding these public domain planet images from NASA (or elsewhere, but I imagine they are all from the Hubble telescope, I don't know too much) that are high quality in terms of **detail** and **pixels/size**. If nothing else it would be helpful to simply link to them if there is no pattern to where they are located.

If there is a pattern to where the high quality images are located, I would be interested too to find ones of comets/asteroids/stars. I have found many high quality images of galaxies which is neat, but not of the planets yet.

Comment: NASA does provide very large rectangular images that can be mapped to spherical surfaces. I am not sure where the site is, I may try to find it later today, but it should be pretty popular. You can also check these: [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/118696/the-solar-systems-yearbook-is-about-to-get-filled-in/), [Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2015-02-solar-yearbook.html), [Mike Brown's site](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/~mbrown/dps.html)

Answer (score 3):

The best NASA images of planets are not from the *Hubble Space Telescope*; they are from the spacecraft that flew by or went into orbit around them. For Uranus and Neptune, this means Voyager 2; for Pluto, this means New Horizons. For Jupiter, this means primarily Voyagers 1 and 2, and especially Galileo and Juno; for Saturn, Voyagers 1 and 2 and (especially) Cassini.

If you google for "[planet-name] planet gallery", you should get some pretty good images that way; also try adding the name of a relevant spacecraft (if you're stuck, check the Wikipedia page for each planet to learn which spacecraft visited them). A few NASA web pages:

- https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/Viking
- https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/saturn/galleries
- https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/neptune/galleries
- https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/dwarf-planets/pluto/galleries

and so forth. (Note that Uranus, even when seen by Voyager 2, is pretty featureless and boring, at least at visible wavelengths.)

You might also try [searching at the Astronomy Picture of the Day site](https://apod.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/apod/apod_search). (Not all of those are necessarily public domain, thoug.)